# Why, in Coq, a record projection expects a Type as argument?

Tags: coq

I would like to formalize a data structure (a string concatenation) in Coq:

```
Require Import List.

Record SeedPassword (A: Type): Type := {
    seed: list A;
    password: list A
}.

Record SeedPasswordConcatenation {A: Type} (S: SeedPassword A): Type := {
    concatenation: list A;
    proof: concatenation = (seed S ++ password S)
}.
```

However, I get an error in the last record:

```
The term "S" has type "SeedPassword A" while it is expected to have type "Type".
```

Why does it expect a `Type`? The projection `seed` should take a `SeedPassword A`, right?

Comment: You just forgot the `A` argument... `proof: concatenation = (seed A S ++ password A S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
About seed.
```

returns:

> ```
> seed : forall A : Type, SeedPassword A -> list A
>
> Argument scopes are [type_scope _]
> seed is transparent
> Expands to: Constant Top.seed
> ```

So, `seed` needs the type, otherwise `A` in `SeedPassword A` will be unbounded.

You can solve the issue with implicit arguments, which Coq will try to infer. One way to do it is to put

```
Set Implicit Arguments.
```

into your file (usually after the imports). Or you can use `Arguments` command like so:

```
Record SeedPassword (A: Type): Type := {
    seed: list A;
    password: list A
}.
Arguments seed {A} _.
Arguments password {A} _.
```